# How does a hyperplane become a linear bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As we know,a hyperplane can seem as a divisor,and a divisor can become a linear bundle,I want to know what the structure of linear bundle is.
For example, the hyperplane is given by $a_0 z_0+a_1 z_1+\ldots+a_n z_n=0$,what is the projective map、transform function and so on?

Comment: How a hyperplane can seem as a divisor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume your question is in the context of algebraic geometry. First, if we are working over affine space, then the hyperplane is cut out by a global function, so the divisor is principal; in particular, this line bundle is trivial.
(In fact, any vector bundle over affine space is trivial, though this is a hard theorem, the [Quillen-Suslin theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Suslin_theorem).)

The question is more interesting when one is working with projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ over a field $k$. In that case, one obtains the standard line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. See section 4.3 of [https://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/linebund.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/linebund.pdf).  The basic idea is that given a line bundle, one obtains the associated Weil divisor by picking a rational section and taking its divisor. So there is a global section $x_0$
of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ (which is basically the structure sheaf twisted by a  homogeneous degree), and where this section does not vanish (and does not vanish with multiplicity one) is just a hyperplane.

In fact, since one can show directly that the Weil class group of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (any hypersurface of degree $d$ being equivalent to $d$ times the hyperplane $\{x_0 = 0\}$, as any homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ divided by $x_0^d$ is a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^n$), so the Picard group of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$ is precisely $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by a copy of $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

The line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the *dual* of the so-called tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$ consisting of pairs $(\ell, p)$ where $\ell$ is a line and $p$ is a point in that line (this is more basic in the topological category).

Comment: Nice answer! I seem to remember someone asking, here or on MO, about how to go from a divisor to a bundle and back etc. Do you remember seeing this? if so could you point me in the direction or rather a source for the argument?

Comment: @Sean: Dear Sean, thanks! You may see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/divisor-line-bundle-correspondence-in-algebraic-geometry (this is in Hartshorne, among other places).

Comment: Perfect！I know a little about algebraic geometry and
get the question in the complex geometry,then I think if the bottem space has no hole just like a sphere,the linear bundle is always trivial.Maybe I ask a silly question.

Comment: @Strongart: Dear Strongart, in fact, complex line bundles on $S^2$ even in the topological category are nontrivial (they are classified by $H^2(., \mathbb{Z})$). In the topological category, line (or more generally vector) bundles over *contractible* spaces are trivial.

Comment: Thanks Akhil! For some reason I have not been able to find my copy of Hartshorne for months... :( (sorry for accidentally posting this as an answer)

Comment: Contractible spaces！I have seen this in someplace,thank you.